# Which pressure points are easy reachable for attack?

Tags: karate, aikido, kung-fu, pressure-points

What I do know about pressure points are some points of body where vital attack could break the nerve system and make human less conscious about surrounding.

but most of them are very behind of strong muscle to apply that much pressure practice of gripping is required deliberately.

I would like to know that are there any pressure points exists that easily could be attack without that much gripping practice.
I mean of course some level of gripping practice needed `kiss of the dragon` like move can't be possible. but not grip like eagle is needed.

Comment: See my answer: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7752/how-do-you-knock-someone-out-using-pressure-points/7754#7754

Comment: @Steve Weigand did read your answer and preaty much got that hitting on vital body parts is only the effective blow and pressure points are not the kind of thing like show in movies or Chinese Medicine Theory and Kyosho-Jitsu. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Pressure points, in general, vary a lot from person to person for location, how covered they are, and how vulnerable that person is to them. The closest ones to "universal" that I can think of almost fall under the "very obvious" category such as the testicles in males (squeeze those with moderate pressure, and they will become much less aware of anything else).

Under somewhat less obvious ones, the web between the thumb and forefinger tends to be pretty widely sensitive (albeit primarily if the hand is largely relaxed) and will definitely distract a person. Just inside the collar-bone, pressing down elicits a pretty universal reaction of knees buckling to reduce pressure. Applying pressure to the nose tends to focus the person's attention on just that, and can provoke tearing in the eyes.

Comment: Did a session covering pressure points recently - and whilst most people would crumple when pressure was exerted correctly - a couple seemed immune completely and the level of pressure and accuracy needed to get a reaction across the class varied wildly.

Comment: Hello @Sean Duggan i did not aware about area between thumb and forefinger. is it backside or front side of hand because i did try to apply pressure (back hand side and front hand side) its not that much paining.

Comment: @NisargDesai: It's Pressure Point LI-4 (Hegu) according to acupressure. You squeeze on both sides. Honestly, the only time I've seen it used in a fight context is when being grabbed with a handshake grip since you can target both sides at once. That and lateral pressure on the thumb are two common methods people use to try to exert dominance in a handshake.

Comment: thanks for description mostly in handshake people do apply pressure on finger`s edge and thumb. may you please share demonstration or video if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing "vital areas" and "pressure points" - they are very different things.

Vital areas are larger in scope, since they involve several/many nerves at once, and can have the effect on consciousness as you pointed out.  So, the eyes, nose, ears, face, neck, solar plexus, stomach, and groin are commonly accessed (attacked) areas in martial arts.  You attack them in some way, say, covering, squeezing, or striking, then they will have varying results - some up to and including loss of consciousness and death.

Pressure points are much smaller in scope and generally involve one nerve point, and can have the effect on a particular body part.  And they are attacked either by strike, rub, or squeeze for the particular effect desired; and sometimes, several areas need to be attacked for a desired effect.  If you want to release a grip, you hit one area.  You want to cause the person to be unable to kick, you attack another area.  The problem with pressure points, as mentioned by Sean Duggan, is that effectiveness can vary from person to person, and from time to time, and from condition to condition.

Your knowledge, your strength; the opponent's ability to resist; the opponent being under the influence of drugs, alcohol, or medication; the opponent is mentally unstable, angry, or injured, or is protected (eg, leather jacket); and the opponent's body physiology.  Any of this can change the effectiveness of the desired effect when a pressure point is attacked.

In a pressure point, the desired effect is almost always pain.  That pain is used as a distraction, a means to release a grip, prevent further attack, etc.  But a vital area need not involve pain.  Of course it can induce pain (eyes, testicles), but it can also render unconsciousness (neck).  Sometimes, a vital area need not be struck: the eyes, for example, can be covered.  So can the mouth.  You know, like with a cloth.  The person can't see or breathe: that's huge.  The mouth and chest can be squeezed.

Now, you ask if they are "easily reachable".  That always depends on context.  For example, you are in a head lock, so your body positioning might be such that the groin or knee is closer than the eyes, and so the eyes are out of reach.  You may have your opponent in a head lock, and so the eyes and neck are more reachable than the groin or knees.

You also asked if there are any that don't require much gripping power.  As I mentioned, pressure points are attacked solely by strike, rub, or squeeze.  Here, power is usually expected; slight strikes/rubs/squeezes will usually not have the desired effect.

But with vital areas, generally, very little gripping is needed, and for cover, squeeze, or strike, little is also needed as well.  A poke to the eyes can be very effective, even if you have an injured finger.  Any male can tell you that the slightest strike, rub, or squeeze on the testes can induce excruciating pain.  The solar plexus is also another area which does not need a tremendous amount of strength to attack.  An arm lock needs very little gripping strength; in fact, if you get the opportunity, you can even do it without gripping at all - just use open hands.

I would bet that the gold medal award for the one vital area requiring least amount of power to attack it would be the thumb lock.  (I'm not sure the thumb qualifies as a vital area, although it is a surprisingly vulnerable thing)  It is versatile, because it's usually more accessible than the eyes (to which I might award the silver medal) only because it's the one body part that extends from the body, and thus allows you more distance to issue than the eyes; and also, it can be used in many instances: weapon disarm, grip release, and other situations might just present itself.

If you manage to get someone in a thumb lock, you can get most people to cry "Uncle!", shine your shoes, and sing Twinkle Little Star with nothing more then your thumb and index finger, all the while using your other hand to play solitaire on your smartphone.  Here, of course, virtually no gripping power is needed at all.

Nevertheless, when you train in martial arts, it does well to train and condition the whole body, even small joints.  For example, I regularly compete or participate in demos.  And in them, I break boards with fingertip.  Is it needed?  No, not really.  But, my hands become very rigid, and an eyeball or throat for a target is easily dispatched, because I train to break boards with the fingertips.

EDIT, To clarify:

Pressure point effectiveness varies from person to person, because some people are able to withstand the effects of PP.  Also, some people's nerves are not unlike veins and arteries: they move.  So if you apply a PP to an area, if that person's nerves or skin moves, you will have a harder time applying the PP.

As to condition to condition, if someone is injured and a nerve is cut off from the brain (eg, a deep laceration), or the area is significantly traumatized through blunt force, then that person's ability to sense the PP effectiveness is significantly weakened.

And as to time to time, there are times you simply cannot apply that PP.  Perhaps you are too fatigued, or maybe you distracted.  Maybe a PP requires a rub, but that PP lies beneath a jacket - that would give protection to the PP area.  Maybe you are wearing gloves or have your hands otherwise occupied (with a grip, a weapon, or your own hands are injured).

There are many who doubt the efficacy of PP.  Perhaps they've never felt them being applied real time.  Perhaps they've seen too many charlatan videos on YouTube.  Perhaps they've not been taught properly or have not had much experience.  Maybe they're not aware that they are already using PP.  Any time you apply a lock, you often attack a PP or VA.  Or perhaps they have a body mechanic that makes them more resistant to them.

The study of PP is not something that can be done in a class, or a couple of classes, or even a couple of weeks of dedicated practice.  Once you understand how the nervous system works, you begin to understand how to apply pressure points - and that can take years of study and earnest practice.

While you study pressure points, be sure not to forego all of your other training.  Pressure points - like any technique you are taught - should always present themselves; you should not go looking for them.  You may live an entire lifetime of fighting and never once have a situation present itself with a juicy pressure point handed to you on a silver platter.  The study of pressure points should lead to many discoveries about how the body works, so even if pressure points don't work well for you or don't seem to yield the results you were expecting, you still should have learned a great deal about other aspects of the body mechanics that are useful in a martial arts (or healing) context.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Jennings i think i need to look for thumb lock. and yes i was confused about Vital area and Vital Pressure Points. and I am not able to understand how pressure point effectiveness can vary from person to person, and from time to time, and from condition to condition. I mean person to person is  still make sense but time to time and condition to condition?