# I've been watching a lot of avatar lately and i've been wondering can we do what Ty Le did in the avatar in real life {I know bending isn't real}

Tags: training, entertainment

I want to know how to paralyze someone using the same stuff Ty Le used like chi blocking,but I can't find anything on the web.

Comment: To help someone answer this question, try to be as specific as possible about what you mean. For example, images or a pointer to where in an episode something takes place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is There a Style of Martial Arts That Can Paralyze?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/is-there-a-style-of-martial-arts-that-can-paralyze)

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.