What causes a person to instantly faint when struck lightly with a knife-hand strike beside the neck?
What causes a person to instantly faint when struck lightly with a knife-hand strike beside the neck? What is the anatomy and physiology that occurs?

I discuss this and more at another question's answer at the following link: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7752/how-do-you-knock-someone-out-using-pressure-points/7754#7754

Same as what happens to religious people when they speak in tongues and convulse on the floor. There's no "there" there — it's all pleasing the Big Man, cultish peer pressure, conformity, gullibility, quackery, fakery, bullshit.

@Dave - Pressure points knockouts are real, however the impact on individuals is varied and some people (clearly yourself being one) are no affected at all. They are not particularly useful in real world as the fighter with the skill to use them has a large number of other highly useful techniques to draw on.

@mattnz I challenge you to show even one non-demo example of a "light" strike to the neck causing someone to pass out. Videos of actual KOs of every real sort are common, so this shouldn't be hard if the phenomenon is real. (Spoiler: all you're going to find are demos because it's the power of social suggestion in cult settings that makes it possible.)

My answer at the link I posted above goes over this specifically. The "pressure point knock-out" phenomenon, as demonstrated by arts like Kyusho-Jitsu from Dillman's Karate, is bogus. There are knock-outs that you can get by strikes to points on the head or the neck (see my link). But those don't have anything to do with the multi-point, 5 element theory knock-out concept from kyusho-jitsu. You won't get KO's if you exclude those head and neck points. KO's only appear to happen with those other points when it's done on believers at a school that practices them. It won't work on other people.

And, as per Steve's answer, the blow to the side of the neck is one of the plausible ones, although it's more than just a light strike, and it is not without danger of causing a blood clot that could migrate to the brain.

To quote from Steve's answer:

.... on the neck, adjacent to the Adam's Apple. Strikes there cause knock-outs by way of the Vagus nerve. The Vagus nerve actually measures the blood pressure of the arteries of the neck. A strike to the Vagus nerve at that location will cause a false measurement of extremely high blood pressure. The brain will receive the high blood pressure signal and will attempt to lower the body's blood pressure. Since blood pressure is actually not high for real, lowering the blood pressure will result in the person fainting. They pass out.


So, you wanna know about the ol' Vulcan death grip, huh? The gentle tap that turns a tough guy into a sack of potatoes? Well, it ain't magic, it's just some bullshit biology. See, your neck, besides holdin' up your goddamn head, is a goddamn superhighway of nerves and blood vessels. It's like the freakin' I-95 of your body, everything important goes through there.
Now, this "knife-hand strike," it ain't about brute force, it's about precision. You're aimin' for a specific spot, the carotid sinus. It's a little bulge on your carotid artery, right here on the side of your neck. Think of it like a little snitch, constantly ratting out your blood pressure to your brain.
When you whack that snitch just right, it freaks out. It sends a message to your brain stem, the reptilian part of your brain that handles all the shit you don't think about, like breathin' and your heart beatin'. The message is basically, "Holy shit! Blood pressure's through the roof! Shut this whole goddamn system down!"
And your brain, bein' the obedient little prick it is, does exactly that. Thump. Lights out. You're on the floor, lookin' like you just lost a fight with a bottle of Jack Daniels.
Now, the physiology, for all you science nerds: The carotid sinus is full of these little sensors called baroreceptors. They're like tiny blood pressure gauges. When you hit 'em, they get overstimulated. They send a signal through the vagus nerve, which is like the goddamn internet cable of your nervous system, straight to the medulla oblongata, the control center in your brain stem. The medulla, in its infinite wisdom, slows the heart rate way down and dilates the blood vessels, droppin' your blood pressure like a goddamn stone. And boom, you're outta commission.
But here's the thing, this ain't some foolproof ninja shit. It depends on a lot of factors: the angle of the strike, the force, the individual's physiology. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes you just end up with a pissed-off dude with a sore neck. So, don't go around tryin' this shit at home, unless you're a trained professional or you really, really hate the person you're with. And even then, think twice. It's all bullshit anyway.
